# does mongodb support subcollections

Tags: mongodb, collections

Is there such a concept as subcollections in mongo, something like a subdocument but supports the full crud api? I would like to organize my db to perform queries like this:

```
db.games.pong.leaderbords.find({score:{'$gt':99}})
```

In other words is there any hierarchy to collections or must I create a fully descriptive name for each collection, as in:

```
db.pongLeaderboard.find({score:{'$gt':99}});
```

EDIT: As Nicolas pointed out the dot notation is allowable. What I meant to ask is can I do this and have `games` and `pong` be proper collections in their own right so I could still do something like

```
db.games.find({name:'pacman'})
```

Comment: Right, after your edit, I'm pretty sure the answer is, unfortunately, a simple "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly legal for collection names to contain the `.` character, so it's entirely possible to organise your data such that your first query is correct.

I'm fairly sure that creating the collection `games.pong.leaderbords` does not create `games`, `games.pong` or `pong` though, so this might not answer your problem.

This type of question is terribly easy to answer for yourself though - just type your query in MongoDB and see what happens. If it fails, it's not possible. If it doesn't, it's possible. MongoDB is good that way. Not only does that give you a definite answer, it also gives you an *immediate* answer without having to wait for someone to try and type your query and post the result.

Comment: I apologize for not describing my issue clearly enough. I do want `games` and `pong` to be collections in there own right, having all the features of a collection but also having subcollections. I couldn't find any documentation for such a feature but was worried I was missing something.

Comment: @gloo there is no subcollections per se, not sure what you define the difference being to be honest however the dot notation does allow for a organisational type subcollection. What would be special about subcollections in your app>

Comment: I don't think you are, no. You can have `games`, `games.pong` and `games.pong.leaderboards` as separate collections, since that's 3 different names. There won't, however, be any sort of dependance between the three except maybe in your own code. Nothing that MongoDB will enforce in any way, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

> What I meant to ask is can I do this and have games and pong be proper collections in their own right so I could still do something like

If I understand you right then no. Those two "subcollections" will have no reference to each other as such, unless you have actually created a `games` collection with data in (`db.games.ping.xx` doesn't count) then this will not work.